# Apache can't find index.html when Alias is added

Tags: apache

I have 2 folders in /var/www/html, serving different parts of my website. Both folders have index.html file. 
If I access the folders using `https://<domain_name>/<folder>`, it works fine.

I want to use folder1 for the website, so I added this Alias line in apache2.conf:

> Alias / /var/www/html/folder1

Now, if I access `https://domain_name`, Apache throws a "Forbidden" error.

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/folder1: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

It seems Apache can't find index.html **only** when the Alias is added.

I have tried everything, from adding this in VirtualHosts and in alias.conf, but with the same result. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it correct set Document root path? Please refer this article https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Comment: @Dipti: Thanks! Set up a virtual host, and it's working fine now.